# Doubt About Counterfactual Regret Derivation

Tags: game-theory

Counterfactual regret minimization is currently an important component of state of the art poker playing algorithms. It was introduced in 2007 in [Regret Minimization in Games with Incomplete Information](http://poker.cs.ualberta.ca/publications/NIPS07-cfr.pdf) by Zinkevich et al.

I'm having trouble verifying one of the crucial results, Theorem 3, which I will restate after giving some definitions.

The context is a perfect recall extensive-form game of incomplete information, repeated for $T$ iterations.
At iteration $t$, we have the strategy profile $\sigma^t$.
$\sigma_i$ denotes the strategy of player $i$ and $\sigma_{-i}$ denotes the strategy of all players except for $i$.
$\Sigma_i$ is the space of behavioral strategies available to player $i$.
$\sigma|_{I\rightarrow a}$ denotes strategy identical to $\sigma$ except that at information set $I$ the player who acts always acts with action $a$.
$u_i(\sigma)$ is the expected payoff for player $i$ under strategy profile $\sigma$.
$A(I)$ are the actions available to the acting player at information set $I$.
$\frak{I}_i$ denotes the information sets of player $i$.
$Z$ is the set of terminal game states.
$\pi^\sigma(h)$ is the probability of reaching game state $h$ under the strategy profile $\sigma$ and $\pi^\sigma(h, h')$ is the probability of going from game state $h$ to $h'$.
$\pi^\sigma(I)$ is the probability that information set $I$ is reached under the strategy profile $\sigma$.
Probabilities $\pi^\sigma$ can be further decomposed to the probability due to player $i$ denoted $\pi^\sigma_i(.)$ and the probability due to players other than $i$ denoted $\pi^\sigma_{-i}(.)$.
$x^+$ denotes $\max(x,0)$.

Define average overall regret of player *i* at time $T$ as:
$$ R^T_i = \frac 1 T \max_{\sigma_i^* \in \Sigma_i} \sum_{t=1}^T u_i(\sigma_i^*, \sigma_{-i}^t) - u_i(\sigma^t)$$

Define counterfactual utility of information set $I$ under strategy profile $\sigma$ as:
$$ u_i(\sigma, I) = \frac {\sum_{h\in I, h'\in Z} \pi^\sigma_{-i}(h)\pi^\sigma(h, h')u_i(h')}{\pi^\sigma_{-i}(I)}$$
Remark: The above seems to be equivalent to the expected payoff to player $i$ under $\sigma$, given that play reaches information set $I$. Just multiply numerator and denominator by $\pi^\sigma_i(I)$.

Define immediate counterfactual regret at information set $I$ as:
$$ R^T_{i, \text{imm}}(I) = \frac 1 T \max_{a \in A(I)} \sum_{t = 1}^T \pi_{-i}^{\sigma^t}(I)(u_i(\sigma^t|_{I \rightarrow a}) - u_i(\sigma^t, I))$$

The authors claim Theorem 3.
$R_i^T \le \sum_{I\in \frak{I_i}} R^{T+}_{i, \text{imm}}(I)$

Their proof lies in Appendix A.1 and requires some additional definitions.

$D(I)$ are the information sets of player $i$ reachable from $I$ and including $I$.
$\sigma|_{D(I)\rightarrow \sigma'}$ is a strategy profile equal to $\sigma$ except in the information sets $D(I)$ where it is equal to $\sigma'$.
$\text{succ}_i^\sigma(I'|I,a)$ is the probability that $I'$ is the next information set of player $i$ given action $a$ awas selected in information $I$ and $\sigma$ is the current strategy. There is a mysterious qualification here.

> If $\sigma$ implies that $I$ is unreachable because of an action of player $i$, that action is changed to allow $I$ to be reachable.

$\text{Succ}_i(I,a)$ is the set of all possible next information sets of player $i$ given $a \in A(I)$ was selected in $I$. $\text{Succ}_i(I) = \cup_{a\in A(I)} \text{Succ}_i(I,a)$.

The full counterfactual regret is defined:
$$R_{i,\text{full}}^T(I) = \frac 1 T \max_{\sigma' \in \Sigma_i} \sum_{t=1}^T \pi_{-i}^{\sigma^t}(I)(u_i(\sigma^t|_{D(I)\rightarrow\sigma'}, I) - u_i(\sigma^t,I))$$

The authors assert equation $(10)$.
$R_{i,\text{full}}^T(I) = \frac 1 T \max_{a \in A(I)} \max_{\sigma' \in \Sigma_i} \sum_{t=1}^T \pi_{-i}^{\sigma^t}(I)[u_i(\sigma^t|_{I\rightarrow a},I) - u_i(\sigma^t, I) + \sum_{I'\in\text{Succ}_i(I,a)} \text{succ}_i^\sigma(I'|I,a)(u_i(\sigma^t|_{D(I)\rightarrow\sigma'},I') - u_i(\sigma^t,I'))]$

I'm just not getting the decomposition here. How can we split off a pure strategy $a \in A(I)$ when the maximization takes place over mixed strategies? Secondly, aren't we double-counting here? For instance, the term $- u_i(\sigma^t, I)$ already incorporates game tree nodes that would occur after taking action $a$ at $I$, yet still we add in the terms $-u_i(\sigma^t, I')$ for every information set $I'$ that is a direct descendent of $I$ after taking action $a$.

Can someone clear up this step for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can derive equation (10) as follows.

$$R_{i,\text{full}}^T(I) = \frac 1 T \max_{\sigma' \in \Sigma_i} \sum_{t=1}^T \pi_{-i}^{\sigma^t}(I)(u_i(\sigma^t|_{D(I)\rightarrow\sigma'}, I) - u_i(\sigma^t,I)) $$

Lemma 1.
Let $\sigma'$ be a strategy for player $i$ whose move at $I$ is the pure move $a$.
$$u_i(\sigma^t|_{D(I)\rightarrow\sigma'}, I) = \sum_{I'\in\text{Succ}_i(I,a)}\text{succ}_i^{\sigma^t}(I'|I,a)u_i(\sigma^t|_{D(I)\rightarrow\sigma'},I)$$

This is a result of the special case of [Law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)
$E[X] = \sum_{A_i} P(A_i)E[X|A_i]$.

Lemma 2.
$$ u_i(\sigma^t|_{I\rightarrow a},I) = \sum_{I'\in\text{Succ}_i(I,a)}\text{succ}_i^{\sigma^t}(I'|I,a)u_i(\sigma^t, I')$$

Again this is a consequence of the law of total expectation.

Using Lemma 1 and 2 we can derive equation (10). We can just focus on the terms inside the sum $\sum_{t=1}^T \pi^{\sigma^t}_{-i}(I)(...)$
$$u_i(\sigma^t|_{D(I)\rightarrow\sigma'}, I) - u_i(\sigma^t,I) + 0 =$$

$$u_i(\sigma^t|_{D(I)\rightarrow\sigma'}, I) - u_i(\sigma^t,I) + u_i(\sigma^t|_{I\rightarrow a},I) - u_i(\sigma^t|_{I\rightarrow a},I)=$$

$$u_i(\sigma^t|_{I\rightarrow a},I) - u_i(\sigma^t,I) + u_i(\sigma^t|_{D(I)\rightarrow\sigma'}, I) - u_i(\sigma^t|_{I\rightarrow a},I)=$$

$$u_i(\sigma^t|_{I\rightarrow a},I) - u_i(\sigma^t,I) + \sum_{I'\in\text{Succ}_i(I,a)}\text{succ}_i^{\sigma^t}(I'|I,a)u_i(\sigma^t|_{D(I)\rightarrow\sigma'},I) - \sum_{I'\in\text{Succ}_i(I,a)}\text{succ}_i^{\sigma^t}(I'|I,a)u_i(\sigma^t, I')=$$

$$u_i(\sigma^t|_{I\rightarrow a},I) - u_i(\sigma^t,I) + \sum_{I'\in\text{Succ}_i(I,a)}\text{succ}_i^{\sigma^t}(I'|I,a)(u_i(\sigma^t|_{D(I)\rightarrow\sigma'},I) - u_i(\sigma^t, I'))=$$

This derivation was discussed on Reddit's [r/gametheory](https://www.reddit.com/r/GAMETHEORY/comments/nq7gly/doubts_about_counterfactual_regret_minimization/h09tvrg?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: To answer the part about splitting off a pure strategy when maximizing over mixed strategies, any pure strategy in the support of a maximizing mixed strategy is also maximizing.